# How to get the whole row from data frame having maximum value for every 7 records in the pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

For ex. consider the data frame given below:

```
    Timestamp  in_speed
   1625638530    268.78
   1625638590    262.75
   1625638650    265.43
   1625638710    270.67
   1625638770    261.13
   1625638830    265.49
   1625638890    266.51
   1625638950    270.54
   1625639010    275.12
   1625639070    267.62
   1625639130    267.20
   1625639190    265.29
   1625639250    261.95
   1625639310    264.39
   1625639370    270.76
   1625639430    291.18
```

I want to extract the whole row containing the maximum value for every 7 rows. Hence, desired output will be:

```
  1625638710    270.67
  1625639010    275.12
  1625639430    291.18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for indices by maximal values and select by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = df.loc[df.groupby(df.index // 7)['in_speed'].idxmax()]
#alternative for not default index
#df = df.loc[df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 7)['in_speed'].idxmax()]
print (df)
     Timestamp  in_speed
3   1625638710    270.67
8   1625639010    275.12
15  1625639430    291.18
```